# Can I set the Password Policy on a GPO using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-domain

I'm trying to automate configuration of a domain controller.

I can create and link a GPO using [Group Policy cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx) in Powershell, but how can I set certain policies like the [Password Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994572(v=ws.10).aspx) for a given GPO, without resorting to the Group Policy Management Editor?

Comment: If there are no cmdlets then write your own PS code to update the relevant registry values.

Comment: @Karan: As far as I can understand, it's possible to set registry values in a GPO, and I should be able to set those using Set-GPRegistryValue. My follow-up question then is – how do I find the path for the Password Policy settings in the registry?

Comment: Use Process Monitor to figure out the keys and values that gpedit modifies.